Azure Service Bus processor IsProcessing:False with not error message
I have this code
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Azure.Core.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using worker.Services;

const string connstr = "Endpoint=.../;SharedAccessKeyName=...";
const string queueName = "...";

Console.WriteLine("Starting the queue client");

// Set the logger, otherwise the processor will eat the exceptions
using AzureEventSourceListener listener =
    AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger(EventLevel.Verbose);

var sbClientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions
{
    TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
};

var client = new ServiceBusClient(connstr, sbClientOptions);

// create the options to use for configuring the processor
var sbProcessorOptions = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
{
    AutoCompleteMessages = false,
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 2,
};

await using ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, sbProcessorOptions);
processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
{
    // the error source tells me at what point in the processing an error occurred
    Console.WriteLine(args.ErrorSource);
    // the fully qualified namespace is available
    Console.WriteLine(args.FullyQualifiedNamespace);
    // as well as the entity path
    Console.WriteLine(args.EntityPath);
    Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

// Processing is happening in the background, we need to wait
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processor - IsProcessing:{processor.IsProcessing} IsClosed:{processor.IsClosed}");
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}

MessageHandler and ErrorHandler are never called and it does not print any errors.
The Console shows:
Starting the queue client
[Verbose] Azure-Messaging-ServiceBus: Creating a ServiceBusClient (Namespace: 'xxx.servicebus.windows.net', Entity name: ''
[Verbose] Azure-Messaging-ServiceBus: A ServiceBusClient has been created (Identifier '').
Processor - IsProcessing:False IsClosed:False

If in the same console app I do
var receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName);
var message = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();
Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);

Then I get messages. So I assume that the connection string/key etc works fine.

Perhaps it's a typo, but there's no call to StartProcessingAsync in the code that you've shared.  Until you start it, the processor is not running.   Once started, it will run until you explicitly stop it.
You may want to read through the Service Bus Processor sample which walks through configuring and starting your processor with context for each step.
